# Complex Many-to-Many JPA CriteriaQuery

Tags: jpa, many-to-many, criteriaquery

I have two entities, Ablum and Image, which are in many to many relationship.
I wanna make a criteria query that to get all Albums and the counts on how many Images they have.
I don't want to get all Albums first then loop the result to get the counts as there would be so many sql requests.
I've been working for 2 nights and complete lost. If cannot find a way out maybe I need to fallback to use SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to digitaljoel's inspiration, I found that CriteriaBuilder has a method call "size" that can be put on collections. Below is the code:

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Object[]> query = cb.createQuery(Object[].class);
    Root<AlbumEntity> albums = query.from(AlbumEntity.class);
    query.select(cb.array(albums.get(AlbumEntity_.id), cb.size(albums.get(AlbumEntity_.images))));
    query.groupBy(albums.get(AlbumEntity_.id));
```

Here the groupBy call is a must otherwise error will occur.
But this method is to load the IDs of AlbumEntity, not the entity itself. The Album entity can be load if below code is used:

```
    query.select(cb.array(albums, cb.size(albums.get(AlbumEntity_.images))));
    query.groupBy(albums.get(AlbumEntity_.id), ...);
```

The groupBy must include all properites of the album entity. And it still does not work if the album entity has blob type property.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to have to make some assumptions since you haven't posted your JPA mapping, so I'm assuming each album has a `List<YourImageClass> images` for the many to many mapping.  With that, something like this would work.

```
select a, size(a.images) from Album a
```

That would return a `List<Object[]>` where `List.get(i)[0]` would be the album and `List.get(i)[1]` would be the corresponding size of the image collection.

Alternately, you could define a simple bean to select into.  Something like

```
public class AlbumResult {
    private Album album;
    private Integer imageCount;
    public AlbumResult( Album a, Integer size ) {
        album = a;
        imageCount = size;
    }
    // getters and setters here
}
```

Then you could do

```
select new AlbumResult(a, size(a.images)) from Album a;
```

I never deal with criteria queries, but the JPQL is simple enough it should be trivial to translate it into a criteria query.

Comment: Thanks digitaljoel, but i can not use JPQL in the project. But your idea inspired me. Thanks a lot:)

Comment: Yeah, you mentioned that you needed a criteria query in your question, that's why in my answer I said that the JPQL should be simple enough to translate into a criteria query, but since I don't ever use criteria queries I figured you would get that done much quicker than I would.  Here's where I got the size function from http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/collection#Criteria_Query_Collection_Expressions_